# What Synctex dependencies are missing under WSL?

Tags: windows, emacs, linux, forward-inverse-search

The setup on my Windows work computer is an Ubuntu instance of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with an X server and the i3 window manager. I use emacs to edit latex and evince as a viewer. I have the same emacs configuration as my (real) Ubuntu machine where forward and backward synchronization works pretty much out of the box between emacs and evince. For information, synctex is provided by texlive on my Ubuntu machine, but by miktex (for linux) under the WSL machine.

However, under WSL the synchronization is not complete. Forward sync (running emacs "TeX-view") brings me to the correct page only and does not highlight the precise region where the cursor is located. Backward sync (ctrl+click in evince) does not work at all.

Are there any dependencies that synctex relies on that are usually found in vanilla Ubuntu, but not in WSL?